# if statement not separating content

Tags: windows, python-2.7

See this snippet of code:

```
exclude = ["BURSAR", "SHOP"]
for name in exclude:
    if name in machineName: # machineName is defined further up in the script.
        inputText.insert("end", machineName + " has been excluded.\n")
    else:
        command = subprocess.Popen( commands here...)
```

It's job is to exclude any machine which includes certain words within it's name.

Currently, if I pass two machines to the script, one of which is called 'BURSAR3' (for example), it will register the fact that it should be excluded, and runs the inputText to show that fact. Unfortunately it also continues to pass the name to the command below, when it shouldn't. I can even replace the 'else:' with 'if name not in exclude:' and it will still fail in the same way!

What have I done wrong here? It looks like it should be so simple...

Thanks,
Chris.
p.s. apologies if the title is rubbish - I couldn't think how to define it better...

Comment: So you're saying that `machineName` is "BURSAR3", and it's running both `insert` and `Popen`? Not too surprising there, because "BURSAR" is in machineName and "SHOP" isn't, so one executes the `if` and one executes the `else`.

Comment: you should loop through the list first before deciding the action to take
i.e. if the name is in the exclude list then the input text, else run the command.

What you're currently doing executes the if or else clause for each element in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the optional `else` after a `for`:

```
exclude = ["BURSAR", "SHOP"]
for name in exclude:
    if name in machineName: # machineName is defined further up in the script.
        inputText.insert("end", machineName + " has been excluded.\n")
        break
else:
    command = subprocess.Popen( commands here...)
```

The `else` is executed ONLY if the for loop completed naturally, without encountering the `break`. Thus, if none of the blacklisted words appear in the machine name, the else block is executed.

Of course, there's an easier way to do this:

```
exclude = ["BURSAR", "SHOP"]
if any((name in machineName for name in exclude)): # machineName is defined further up in the script.
    inputText.insert("end", machineName + " has been excluded.\n")
else:
    command = subprocess.Popen( commands here...)
```